# How to write Source for image from Resources/Images subfolder

Tags: xaml, maui

I have two PNG-files:
`Resoucres/Images/image1.png` and `Resoucres/Images/subfolder/image2.png`
so, I want to set they as `Source` for `Image`:

when I set 1st image:
`<Image ... Source="image1.png" />`
all working correctly, but when I try to set 2nd image:

`<Image ... Source="subfolder.image2.png" />`
image isn't displaying.

So, how I need to write the path of the 2nd image?

Comment: For more information you can refer to this [Add images to a .NET MAUI app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/images?view=net-maui-7.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An image can be added to your app project by dragging it into the Resources\Images folder of the project, where its build action will automatically be set to MauiImage.

**Images can also be added to other folders of your app project. However, in this scenario their build action must be manually set to MauiImage in the Properties window.**

So you can right click the image2.png file select the `properties` then change the `Build Action` to `MauiImage` and you can use the image directly.

```
<Image ... Source="image2.png" />
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Question is, even if I put the image in a folder such as Images/xyz/image2.png, it can still only be referenced as image2.png and xyz/image2.png does not work. Is there a solution for this ?